# How does the Salesforce usage metrics pilot differ from other analytics apps?

Tags: analytics, analytic-snapshots

Does it provide more data than things such as Google Analytics or SALYTICS? It seems like it does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by usage metrics pilot you're referring the to following:
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/api/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_usage_metrics_intro.htm

If this is the case, it gives you more information about how organizations who have installed a managed package you have published are using your application.  Specifically, it will let you pull the number of records stored in Custom Objects and the number of times each VF Page was accessed in the installed orgs.

Also, I'm not certain about this, but I don't think Google Analytics could give you any information about orgs which are not your but have installed your managed package.

Comment: Here's a blog post which explains in much more detail... https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2014/04/get-better-visibility-business-announcing-usage-metrics-pilot-feature.html?language=en

Answer (score 0):

This Pilot does the same thing as Google Analytics. However, it will contain the exact information from Salesforce's side. So, you will not need to cross check the info with any other source.